# Testcontainers access denied

Tags: mariadb, testcontainers, spring-boot-testcontainers

I try to create JpaTest, for this I need a container with mariaDb. So I try create it:

```
private static final String CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME = TestcontainersConfiguration.getInstance()
        .getEnvVarOrProperty("mariadb.container.image", "mariadb:10.2.18");


    private static final MariaDBContainer<?> PRIMARY_MARIADB_SQL_CONTAINER = new MariaDBContainer<>(
        DockerImageName
            .parse(CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME )
            .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("mariadb")
    )
        .withDatabaseName("db")
        .withUsername("test")
        .withPassword("password")
        .withPrivilegedMode(true)
        .withInitScript("mariadb/init.sql");
```

Without last `withInitScript` all work fine, but when I add sql I have an error:
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'test'@'%' to database 'test_schema'`

And in my init.sql I have:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test_schema;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_schema.* TO 'test'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Please check you rights, using: `show grants for 'test'@'%'\G`.  This is needed because of the error "Access denied...."

Comment: Can you avoid the need for a init script with ` .withDatabaseName("test_schema")`? Do you need 2 databases? `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` also unneeded. "mariadb:10.2.18" - why such an old unmaintained version?

Comment: @danblack yes, I need 2 schemas

Comment: Was [requested](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27638), [pull request welcome](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `.withInitScript("mariadb/init.sql");` with `withCopyFileToContainer` setting for init-script execution

```
.withCopyFileToContainer(
    MountableFile.forClasspathResource("mariadb/init.sql"),
            "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
);
```

Comment: yes, this work. But if I want use 2 or more files for init, how can I add them not use for each `withCopyFileToContainer`?

Comment: Are those files in the same directory? if yes and you don't want to use `withCopyFileToContainer` multiple times so you can try this way `MountableFile.forClasspathResource("mariadb"), "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"`. (I assume those init files are in /mariadb)